# JQuery & CSS - hover and .mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to display a class `.div-TQA-SF006-U-static` and hide `.div-TQA-SF006-U-160`

And when mouse over `.TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent`, display a class `.div-TQA-SF006-U-160` and hide `.div-TQA-SF006-U-static`

Trying to achieve this using JQuery and CSS but facing difficulty right now - if I have missed out any other important information, please let me know. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

[JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/syd2uct2/4/)

Comment: What difficulty exactly...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a heads-up, the fiddle you linked doesn't include JQuery, so it's not going to be able to run at all. You can fix this with the gear icon in the Javascript editor box - [here's a fork](https://jsfiddle.net/xpk82w65/) with that fixed, plus the solution I came up with below.

Anyway, here's one way to achieve what you're after, although there are probably more efficient ones; I think toggling a css class is usually preferred to .show() and .hide(), but use what works for you.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").on('mouseover', function() {
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").hide();
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").show();
  });
  $(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").on('mouseout', function() {
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").show();
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
.div-TQA-SF006 .td-suspension-child-row2:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.table-suspension-list {
  border: 0;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  border-bottom: 1px solid white;
  background-color: #1F497D;
  color: white;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber-bottom {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  background-color: #1F497D;
  color: white;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber div {
  color: white;
}

.table-suspension-list .partNumber-bottom div {
  color: white;
}

.table-suspension-list .partDescription {
  border: 1px solid #1F497D;
  color: #1F497D;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.table-suspension-list .partDescription div {
  color: #1F497D;
}

.table-suspension tbody {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #002060;
}

.table-suspension th {
  background-color: white;
  border: 0;
  border-top: 2px solid #002060;
  padding: 10px 0 10px 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-family: erasFamily;
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #002060;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.td-suspension-parent {
  background-color: #deeaf6;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.td-suspension-child {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.td-suspension-child-row2 {
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.td-suspension-child div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td-suspension-child-row2 div {
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px;
}

.div-TQA-SF006-U-160 {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="div-TQA-SF006">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th colspan="6">
        SPECIFICATIONS
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="3" style="width: 50%">Part Number</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="3" style="width: 50%">Description</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-child" colspan="3">TQA-SF006</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child" colspan="3">Underslung Air Suspension for 10 Ton Axle</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent" colspan="6">Available Ride Height</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent">160mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-200mm-parent">200mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-250mm-parent">250mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-275mm-parent">275mm</div>
        </td>
        <td class="td-suspension-child-row2" style="width:20%">
          <div class="TQA-SF006-U-300mm-parent">300mm</div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

&nbsp;

<div class="div-TQA-SF006-U-static">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th>
        Spare Parts
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">Hover mouse over desired Ride Height for pop-up information</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div class="div-TQA-SF006-U-160">
  <table class="table-suspension">
    <tbody>
      <th colspan="6">
        SPARE PARTS
      </th>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SPA07</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-PB006</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-AB08</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SA08</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-UB001</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-parent">TQA-SPA20</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Parabolic Spring Straight Type</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Pivot Bolt Kit</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Air Spring</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Shock Absorber</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">U-Bot Kit</td>
        <td class="td-suspension-chlid">Spring Bush</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: I changed my jquery function to how you did and it worked perfectly, thanks. 

I now want to show spare part information (.div-TQA-SF006-U-160) always even after mouse leaves the div class - would you be able to help with this as well by any chance?

[Updated your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xpk82w65/1/)

Comment: Sure - just remove the second function from my sample, the 'mouseout' one.

Comment: I mean because I have other divs after this code, I want to keep both mouseover and mouseout function and have an additional function that keeps displaying the spare part information `.div-TQA-SF006-U-160` when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following code to make the spare parts information disappear when the mouse leaves.

```
$(".TQA-SF006-U-160mm-parent").mouseleave(function(){
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-static").show();
    $(".div-TQA-SF006-U-160").hide();
});
```

Comment: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/syd2uct2/9/)

Spare parts has a class .div-TQA-SF006-U-static so I put the class to hide on mouseleave function. It still doesn't work in JSFiddle for me though.

Comment: Oh, I forgot. The JSFiddle hasn't referenced JQuery if that was your problem

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot to add jquery source and after I added it, it worked. Thanks.